# Hook after successful installation

Tags: android, installation, android-package-managers

I got an activity that launches the package manager for installing an application contained in the phone's SDCard.

Is there some kind of hook that gets executed if the installation was successful|unsuccessful?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might register something in your original application for broadcasts of ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED (the newly installed application won't receive this broadcast)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED

Not sure if there's anything for failure (or user decision not to confirm the installation)